# OpenAL not detecting any playback or capture devices

Tags: audio, ubuntu-20.04, alsa, openal, openal-soft

I have tried to use the OpenAL API to play some 3D spatialized sounds. I can install it on my Raspberry Pi successfully with a simple `sudo apt install libopenal1 libopenal-dev` but when I try this on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS it will not playback audio and shows this output for `openal-info`:

```
Available playback devices:
    !!! none !!!
Available capture devices:
    !!! none !!!
Default playback device: 
Default capture device: 
ALC version: 1.1
[ALSOFT] (WW) Failed to open playback device: Could not open /dev/dsp: No such file or directory
[ALSOFT] (WW) Error generated on device (nil), code 0xa004

!!! Failed to open default device !!!
```

When I use `ALC_DEVICE_SPECIFIER` within the API I get the same results. This means I cannot playback my OpenAL buffer to my headphones. Although I **can** do `aplay out.wav` with playback going through the headphones. So I do not think it is an ALSA issue.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I think it might have something to do with the backends that OpenAL uses but I would not know how to check that.